# how to split large csv into multiple small csv using linux?

Tags: linux, csv, split

Need to split **large csv file** into multiple files by lines using php and linux.

CSV contains -

```
"id","name","address"
"1","abc","this is test address1 which having multiple  newline
separators."
"2","abc","this is test address2
which having multiple newline  separators"
"3","abc","this is test address3.
which having multiple
newline separators."
```

I used linux comand - split -l 5000 testfile.

But it can not able to split csv in correct format because in csv there is one field address having multiple newline characters so command with split file from that line.

I've also tried to use PHP:

```
$inputFile = 'filename.csv';
$outputFile = "outputfile";
$splitSize = 5000;
$in = fopen($inputFile, 'r'):
$header = fgetcsv($in);
$rowCount = 0;
$fileCount = 1;

while (!feof($in)) { 
    if (($rowCount % $splitSize) == 0) {
        if ($rowCount > 0) {
            fclose($out);
        }   
        $filename = $outputFile . $fileCount++;
        $out = fopen($filename .'.csv', 'w');
        chmod($filename,777);
        fputcsv($out, $header);
    }   
    $data = fgetcsv($in);
    if ($data) {
        fputcsv($out, $data);
        $rowCount++;
    }   
}
fclose($out);
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Use a programming language which is able to parse CSV

Comment: I tried it by php but it will take too much time. Is there any other solution to fix this issue?

Comment: PHP should be pretty fast. Can you show the PHP code you have used?

Comment: Please do not post code as a comment, you see, it is hard to read. Edit your question instead. (I did for you, because it is your first post)

Comment: The PHP code looks good, it should work well

Comment: It split file but while opening splitted file will gives error Unsupported file format.

Comment: resolved, having problem with editor on linux operating system .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'require "csv"
        f = ARGV.shift
        CSV.foreach(f).with_index{ |e, i|
            File.write("#{f}.#{i}", CSV.generate_line(e, force_quotes: true))
        }' file.csv
```

Php:

```
<?php
    $inputFile = 'file.csv';
    $outputFile = 'file.out';
    $splitSize = 1;
    if (($in = fopen($inputFile, 'r'))) {
        $header = fgetcsv($in);
        $rowCount = 0;
        $fileCount = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($in))) {
            if (($rowCount % $splitSize) == 0) {
                if ($rowCount > 0) {
                    fclose($out);
                }
                $filename = $outputFile . ++$fileCount . '.csv';
                $out = fopen($filename, 'w');
                chmod($filename, 755);
                fputcsv($out, $header);
            }
            fputcsv($out, $data);
            $rowCount++;
        }
        fclose($out);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux has a great little utility called split, which can take a file and split it into chunks of whatever size you want, eg 100 line chunks.

However, for CSV files etc, each chunk generally needs to have the header row in there. Unfortunately the split command doesn’t have an option for that. However with a little bit more code you can achieve it.

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | split -l 4 - split_
for file in split_*
do
head -n 1 file.txt > tmp_file
cat $file >> tmp_file
mv -f tmp_file $file
done
```